# Selecting multiple properties in Javascript or D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to remove a few data points from a map created in D3.

Here I'm removing a property with name matching "Luxembourg", but I would also like to remove a property with name matching "Liechtenstein". How should I write this?

```
.filter(function(labels) {
  return labels.properties.name != "Luxembourg";
})
```

I have tried using [javascript references](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2013/03/14/better-ways-of-comparing-a-javascript-string-to-multiple-values/) but I'm having trouble applying these.

Comment: The article you link to is pretty comprehensive and has excellent examples. What trouble do you have applying those to your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```
.filter(function(labels) {             
   var toFilter = ['Luxembourg', 'Liechtenstein']
   return toFilter.indexOf(labels.properties.name) !== -1
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Something simple like this will do:

```
var countriesToRemove = [ "Luxembourg",  "Liechtenstein"]

data.filter(function(labels) {
  return countriesToRemove.indexOf(labels.properties.name) >= 0
})
```